# How to parameterize and access different sub objects of a class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a object say - car

Inside car object i have some high level data and then few subobjects say engine, variant .

so the structure looks like

Data set 1 :

car= {name:"ab" , price:"8l", tata:<object_engine>, kia:None}

engine ={engine_type: diesel, automatic: yes}

Data set 2 :

car= {name:"ab" , price:"8l", tata:None, kia:<object_engine>}
engine ={engine_type: "petrol", automatic: "No"}

Now I want to access data set 1 and data set 2 in a generic way

can I have tata and kia as variables and access the engine details in a generic way

something like --- car.manufacturer.engine_type

where the manufacturer can be tata or Kia

Comment: Could you use valid python syntax?

Comment: You code currently looks like javascript, if you quote the field names you get what are called "dictionaries" in Python. If you want to define `Car` and `Engine` object types then you should define them as _classes_, see https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/ this will allow you to use dotted attribute access syntax like `somecar.engine.engine_type`. See also https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html for a quick way to define such classes once you have understood a bit the first article

Comment: I'd suggest instead of using the manufacturer name as a field name (in which case you should stick with dictionaries) have something more like `manufacturer: "Kia", engine: <engine>`... that way every instance has the same field names, just different values